# When was the most amount of commercial trade carried by sail powered ships?

Tags: trade, age-of-sail

What was the apogee of sailed based trade? Which civilisation, in which period, had the largest volume of maritime trade under sail?

Comment: What has your research shown so far? Also, please provide more details. [Sailboat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailboat) is a very large category of boats.

Comment: I just want to know when the economy was at its apogee using sailboat to import export product. The answer I expected is a period, or a civilisation name.

Comment: @crg It sounds like you're asking for when the volume of trade by sailing ships was at its biggest. I've edited the question based on that understanding, but please clairfy if that is not the case. The problem with your current wording is that (1) "when we used sailing ships" is not a discrete period; they're still in use right up to today, and therefore the US economy is the biggest economy. (2) you asked about economy but also traffic under sail; these are not equivalent measures as trade is only a fraction of any economy, and huge land based economy could have next to no sailing ships.

Comment: (1) Is this international trade only or do you want to include coastal trade? (The transport of British coal by sailing ship to other parts of Britain, for example, was a big business.) (2) I'm guessing that things like fishing are not included.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some contributors of the forum will ask you about previous research, but anyway I will answer.

The most important sail merchant fleet during the history, and throughout the world, in activity was the clipper fleet of the 19th century. This "clipper fleet" actually consisted in a lot more of other types of boats, especially of military type, but the clipper were the figurehead of this period.

Please note that this answer considers long-range travelling. For short range and very short range, there might be very numerous small sailboats (even more including fishing boats) that totalized a large amount of commercial trade.
The answer also does not take into account the trade compared to population size.

The maritime traffic consisted mainly in the following commercial roads:

- Cotton imported from India to United Kingdom
- Asia to Europe and return commercial trade, that saw heavy involvement of the clippers to transport tea (from China) faster and faster
- African trade: this was more and more important as long as colonial empires extended
- South American trade and passenger transportation

Note that this apogee ended with the use of steam-powered boats.

Comment: This answer is distinctly lacking in any evidence. Who owned this "clipper fleet"? What volume of trade did it generate? How did this compare with other fleet operators? How did this compare with other time periods? How did it change with regard to the introduction of steam services? etc.